# Intent not running after clicking on StatusBar Notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am implementing broadcast receiver on my application. The problem is that when application is running then whenever a notification comes and user click on it it intent correctly. But if notification comes and application is not running then on the first time intent is performed correctly. But nothing happened except notification is deleted on click. Any suggestion. I will provide code if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue.

add this line to your intent

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: as i said earlier notifications are intented correctly if application is running.

Comment: ok just change the id to some random number all the time.     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(thisContext, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: yes and add this method in your activity @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    setIntent(intent);
}

Comment: overriding the method didnot help anything. I think their is problem with intenting

Comment: I have added the code used in main activity . I think the main activity is called (when application is running ) that is why notifications are working fine. But whenever the notification are clicked directly they doonot call main activity and thus no new notification appears. Is their any thing i can provide to you to solve the issue

Comment: its not working i have not used it properly. and made logic bit complex :(

Answer (score 0):

Have intent-filter in the AndroidManifest.xml, it will wake your app up.

Comment: can you please elaborate or be little specific.